# Apache Storm and Docker Swarm, where can i see the output on my stdout?

Tags: java, docker, apache-storm, docker-swarm

So I'm new on docker and is the first time that I use the docker swarm with apache storm, I used storm only on my machine with a custom environment(zookeeper and storm) and see the logs, in this case, is easy but how can I see the logs and the output on my stdout?
This is my stack.yml file:

```
version: '3'
    services:
    nimbus:
        image: storm:2.1.0
        container_name: nimbus
        command: storm nimbus  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"  -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        links:
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "6627:6627"
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./TopologyJar:/TopologyJar

    zookeeper:
        image: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
             - "2181:2181"


    storm-ui: 
        image: storm:2.1.0
        container_name: storm-ui
        command: storm ui  -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
        depends_on: 
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        links: 
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"

    supervisor:
        image: storm:2.1.0
        command: storm supervisor -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"  -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
        container_name: supervisor
        depends_on:
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        links:
            - nimbus
            - zookeeper
        restart: always
```

Thanks a lot.